# Update Table with foreign key in oracle 10.2

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have one table `ROUTE_DETAILS` with column `ROUTE_NUMBER` and `ROUTE_NAME`.

I have another table `CUSTOMER_DETAILS` with column `CUST_CODE`, `CUST_NAME`, `ROUTE_NUMBER`. Here route number is the foreign key of `ROUTE_DETAILS`.

`ROUTE_DETAILS` is parent table and `CUSTOMER_DETAILS` is child table.

Data in `ROUTE_DETAILS`:

```
ROUTE_NUMBER        ROUTE_NAME
RN0001            ROUTE1
RN0002            ROUTE2
RN                ROUTE3
```

Data in `CUSTOMER_DETAILS`:

```
CUST_CODE        CUST_NAME       ROUTE_NUMBER
CC0001         CUSTOMER1        RN0001
CC0002         CUSTOMER2        RN
```

Now the problem is when I am trying to update `ROUTE_NUMBER` from `ROUTE_DETAILS` or update `ROUTE_NUMBER` from `CUSTOMER_DETAILS` an error is shown: *integrity constraints violation child record found*

Query is:

```
update ROUTE_DETAILS 
   set ROUTE_NUMBER = 'RN0003' 
 where ROUTE_NUMBER = 'RN'
```

same thing happen when I am trying to update customer_details.

Answer (score 4):

The only option I see is to change the FK constraint to "DEFERRABLE".

Then you can change both rows in a single transaction as the constraint is checked when you commit the data:

```
update ROUTE_DETAILS set ROUTE_NUMBER ='RN0003' where ROUTE_NUMBER ='RN';
update CUSTOMER_DETAILS set ROUTE_NUMBER ='RN0003' where ROUTE_NUMBER ='RN';
commit;
```

See the manual for details on how to change the FK constraint.

You if you set the constraint to "INITIALLY IMMEDIATE" you need to run `set constraints deferred` before running the updates.

**Edit**, here is a complete example:

### Setup table and constraints:

```
create table route_details
(
 route_number varchar(20) not null primary key
);

create table customer_details
(
   cust_code varchar(20) not null primary key,
   route_number varchar(20) not null
);

alter table customer_details
  add constraint fk_route_number 
     foreign key (route_number)
     references route_details (route_number)
  deferrable
  initially immediate;


insert into route_details (route_number)
values ('RN0001');

insert into route_details (route_number)
values ('RN');

insert into customer_details (cust_code, route_number)
values ('CC0001', 'RN0001');

insert into customer_details (cust_code, route_number)
values ('CC0002', 'RN');

commit;
```

### Run the update:

```
set constraints all deferred;

update ROUTE_DETAILS set ROUTE_NUMBER ='RN0003' where ROUTE_NUMBER ='RN';
update CUSTOMER_DETAILS set ROUTE_NUMBER ='RN0003' where ROUTE_NUMBER ='RN';
commit;
```

Comment: @ManishSasmal:"not working" is not a valid Oracle error message. You did change the definition of the foreign key, did you?

Comment: i did not mean that. what i was saying that this procedure fails.. follow Joe's answer its better and working..

Comment: @ManishSasmal: see my edit (btw: "fails" is also not a valid error message)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you cannot update the parent primary key if a child is referencing that key value.

Also you cannot update the child to have a foreign key value that does not reference a primary key value in the parent table.

So, you can either:

1)Relax the constraint temporarily while you make your changes, being sure to re-apply it afterwards.

Or

2)Delete the child row, update the parent row, then re-insert the child with the new foreign key value.

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts on this...

Firstly you should not be changing the value of your primary key, the whole point of a primary key is that it does not change.

If however you must make this change, there are two ways I know of to do it.

1. Insert 'RN0003' as a new row in route_details.  Then update all affected customers.  Then delete the RN row.  So:

   insert into route_number values ('RN0003','ROUTE3');

   update customer_details set route_number = 'RN0003' where route_number = 'RN';

   delete from route_details where route_number = 'RN';
2. Use deferred keys as described here:

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Foreign_key

Comment: I believe the definition of "primary key" states that it is unique, not that it does not change. Ideally it won't need to change, but it does happen in real life where things are messy.

Answer (score 1):

The referencial actions includes `ON UPDATE`.

*CASCADE: Delete or update the row from the parent table and automatically delete or update the matching rows in the child table. Both `ON DELETE CASCADE` and `ON UPDATE CASCADE` are supported.

So you can use `ON UPDATE CASCADE` referencial action on [your foreing key](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.6-en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-referential-actions).

```
alter table customer_details
  add constraint fk_route_number 
     foreign key (route_number)
     references route_details (route_number)
     ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

For NDB tables, `ON UPDATE CASCADE` is not supported.